# Linked Server using ODBC too slow

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, odbc

The scenario is that developers used a linked server object on `ServerM` to reach `ServerST`. This linked server was setup as a "SQL Server" type using a domain login that exists as a login on `ServerST`.

Now the developers require this linked server object (named `ServerST`) to be reconfigured to point at `ServerAR` (even though confusingly the object would still be named `ServerST`). This allows them to save time rewriting a lot of code, time they do not have.

Now I can create a new linked server on `ServerM` of the type "Other data source" and provide a connection string that works. However a query on the original linked server that took 5s took 46s using the new linked server.

So my question is how do I provide a linked server named `ServerST`, that points to `ServerAR` and operates at the same speed.

All servers are on SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.

The code I currently use to create the slow linked server is:

```
sp_addlinkedserver 'ServerST', ' ', 'MSDASQL', '', '',  
    'Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerST;Database=theDB;Uid=link_ServerM;Pwd={P@ssw0rd};'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the SQLNCLI10 provider? Are you required to use MSDASQL?

Here is a `sp_addlinkedserver` script adding a linked server named `ServerST` that points to `ServerAR`.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ServerST', @srvproduct=N'ServerST', 
    @provider=N'SQLNCLI10', @datasrc=N'ServerAR'
```

**Update 19/082014**

Download [SQL Query Stress Tool](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/sqlquerystressdownload.asp) to compare performance of both SQL Servers, ServerST and ServerAR.

[image]

**Scripting out your existing Linked Server**

This will also include any specially defined parameters such as collation and time out configurations.

[image]

Comment: Have you tested the difference in performance between ServerAR and ServerST? Perhaps the slowness is coming from there. Try this application on both servers, using the same parameters: http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/

Comment: For testing purposes all 3 linked servers currently go to ServerST but using different methodolgy. SQL Server type, SQLNCLI10 and MSDASQL. The latter two operate equally slower than the first. I don't think a stress test tool will be of aid.

Comment: How is ServerAR different from ServerST? According to your question, ServerAR appears to be replacing ServerST. Or is that not what's happening?

Comment: I don't feel this is relevant but ServerST is a testing box (non production) whilst ServerAR is not currently defined (it may be the production version of ServerST), they just need the facility to look elsewhere via reconfiguring the linked server object. My dilemma is providing a configurable linked server seems to be slower, even when comparing against the same two servers (ServerM->ServerST).

Comment: Wait. I'm terribly sorry. I've somehow got confused by the estimated cost of the batches in the execution plans window. Your original suggest was equally FAST as the SQL Server linked server. I can't apologise enough for the wasted time and confusion. Thankyou.

Comment: No worries, I was glad to help

Comment: @Paul Why did you uncheck the answer?